# Error al pasar listado desde acción de controlador a vista

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo un problema en el código que realizamos, por lo cual solicito de su ayuda de favor. Soy novato...

Tengo el siguiente controlador: `Grupos`,  la acción: `Index`

```
            public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<vGpoTutorias> dbGrupos;
        using (kardexEntities bdKardex = new kardexEntities())
        { 
            dbGrupos = (from x in bdKardex.vGpoTutorias select x).ToList();
        }
        return View(dbGrupos);
    }
```

Tengo definido el modelo `Grupos` dentro de la carpeta `Models`, `vGrupos` es una vista de la base de datos sin filtrar.

Mi intención es llamar a la vista `Index` pasándole el listado, pero me envía error al recibirla en la vista:

Aquí la vista:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-md-4 ">
        <label class="control-label">Capture RPE de Docente:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 ">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 ml-auto">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 ml-auto">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-md-4 ">
        <input type="text" id="txtRPE" placeholder="Capture RPE de Docente" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 ">
        <input type="button" value="Buscar Docente" id="btnBuscar" class="btn btn-info" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 ml-auto">
        <label class="control-label">Confirmación de datos del Docente:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtDocente" class="form-control" readonly />
        <input type="text" id="txtCorreo" class="form-control" readonly />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-md-12 ml-auto">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <h3 class="header smaller lighter blue">Relación de Grupos en los que Imparte Clase el Docente y NO ES TUTOR.</h3>
            <table id="ticketsa" class="table table-striped table-bordered " style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Clave del Grupo</th>
                        <th>Ciclo</th>
                        <th>Periodo</th>
                        <th>Clave Materia</th>
                        <th>Materia</th>
                        <th>Clave Carrera</th>
                        <th>Carrera</th>
                        <th>Clave Maestro</th>
                        <th>Estado</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    @foreach (var p in Model)
                    {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@p.id</td>
                        <td>@p.cve_gpo</td>
                        <td>@p.cic_esc</td>
                        <td>@p.per_imp</td>
                        <td>@p.cve_mat</td>
                        <td>@p.nombre_materia</td>
                        <td>@p.cve_car </td>
                        <td>@p.nombre_carrera</td>
                        <td>@p.cve_maes</td>
                        <td>@p.iestado</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    }
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Este es el error:
Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'. El elemento de modelo pasado al diccionario es de tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Coordinador.Models.vGpoTutorias]', pero este diccionario requiere un elemento de modelo de tipo System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Coordinador.Models.Grupos.GruposModel]'.

Comment: ¿Tu declaración @Model  la puedes mostrar así como las clases que intervienen?

Comment: Saludos, no se que paso, al copiar el código a aquí al foro, en la vista al inicio tengo: @model List<Coordinador.Models.Grupos.GruposModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Controlador = "Asignar Grupos";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Asigne / Actualice Grupos a Tutores";
}, no se a que se deba el error mencionado en la descripción de mi pregunta al final. Gracias

Comment: Al parecer la clase  `vGpoTutorias`  no es del tipo `GruposModel`. En todo caso debería ser `@model List<Coordinador.Models.vGpoTutorias> ` que es lo que están pasando realmente.

Comment: Saludos, Juan Carlos, ingrese a la clase vGpoTutorias y veo el modelo que he definido Grupos, con la misma cantidad de campos, observo que desde vGpoModel uno de los campos se declaran como Double y en el modelo Grupos lo declare como int.. será eso lo que me este dando lata. Depurando en la accion Index del controlador Grupos si lleva cargada la información....

Comment: Saludos Juan Carlos, realice un cambio @model List<Coordinador.Models.vGpoTutorias> pero no se si sea correcto, ya que estoy haciendo referencia directamente a la vista, pero revisando el código en ningún momento utilizo el GruposModel para recibir los datos... por lo que hice referencia a la vista de la BD es correcto así ?...Gracias

Comment: Toma: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY este workshop te ayudará a mejorar con ASP.net MVC

Comment: Te funcionó? Lo pongo como respuesta. No entiendo `por lo que hice referencia a la vista de base de datos`. Te explico cuando pase el comentario a respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer la clase `vGpoTutorias` no es del tipo `GruposModel`. El error indica que en tu vista utilizas: `@model List<Coordinador.Models.Grupos.GruposModel>`, sin embargo, la vista esta recibiendo un modelo de tipo `List<Coordinador.Models.vGpoTutorias>`.

En tu controlador en el método `Index()`, se refleja exactamente lo que indica el error:

1. Cuando el usuario hace una solicitud a **/Grupo/Index**, el sistema
   busca al controlador `GrupoController` y ejecuta el método `Index()`. En
   el código se puede apreciar que en este utilizas la
   variable `dbGrupo` de tipo `List<vGpoTutorias>`  para almacenar la
   información de tutorias que lees desde la base de datos.
2. Cuando se ejecuta: `return View(dbGrupo)`, el sistema toma el
   nombre del método en este caso `Index` y busca y carga la vista o archivo 
   `Index.cshtml` y trata de poner el contenido de la lista `dbGrupo`, sin embargo, la vista espera una lista de tipo: `<Coordinador.Models.Grupos.GruposModel>` y aquí se
   el produce el error.

Para solucionar el problema debes cambiar el modelo en `Index.cshtml` por:  @`model List<Coordinador.Models.vGpoTutorias>` que es lo que realmente devuelves desde el controlador `Index()`. Durante este proceso la base de datos solo  intervino para llenar los datos que se presentaran. Si bien tiene una clase con el mismo nombre que la vista en la base de datos `vGpoTutorias` ambas tienen funcionalidades dentro de su contexto. Tu clase `vGpoTutorias`, si quieres puedes ponerle el nombre que quieras, siempre que no cambie su contenido, seguirá recibiendo los datos de la vista `vGpoTutorias`. Espero hacerme entender.

Comment: Gracias Juan Carlos eso mismo realice...